# VSTO auto added Watermark is getting distorted , C# VSTO

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, watermark

all I am new to VSTO and c#,
I'm trying to add a watermark to word document through VSTO automation.
I'm able to add watermark but after adding some text watermark is getting distorted (height is decreasing)

[This is a distorted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRfBZ.png) 
it is a bit blur, sorry for it.

Let me know if you need any information

Thanks in advance
below is my code

```
foreach (Word.Section section in doc.Sections)
            {
                Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                Word.Shape shape = 
                    section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Shapes
                    .AddTextEffect(MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect2, "confidential", "Calibri", 5, 
                MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0, ref oMissing);
                //shape.Select(ref oMissing);
                shape.Name = "WaterMark";
                shape.Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                shape.TextEffect.NormalizedHeight = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                shape.TextEffect.FontItalic = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                shape.TextEffect.FontBold = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                shape.Fill.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                shape.Fill.Solid();
                shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 12632256;
                shape.Fill.Transparency = (float)0.5;
                shape.Rotation = 315;
                shape.LockAspectRatio = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                shape.Left = (float)Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
                shape.LeftRelative = (float)-999999;
                shape.Top = (float)Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
                shape.TopRelative = (float)-999999;
                shape.Height = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CentimetersToPoints((float)3.65);
                shape.Width = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CentimetersToPoints((float)12.62);
                shape.WrapFormat.Type = Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapBehind;
                shape.WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = -1;
                shape.WrapFormat.DistanceBottom = 0;
                shape.WrapFormat.DistanceLeft = 9;
                shape.WrapFormat.DistanceRight = 9;
                shape.WrapFormat.DistanceTop = 0;
                shape.WrapFormat.Side = WdWrapSideType.wdWrapBoth;
                shape.RelativeVerticalPosition = Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin;
                shape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin;
                shape.WidthRelative = (float)-999999;
                doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekMainDocument;
                

            }
```